# Layout with flexbox property

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In this layout, I want to place a circle (with fixed size) at the intersection of the column and a line on the bottom left corner of the page (which should be a no scroll page). The circle should look like this image.

I’ve started doing it with the flexbox property, however this was the first time I used this property and I am not getting how to do this.

Does anyone know how can I do it?

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="hud1">
        <div class="gps box"></div><!-- /gps -->
        <div class="info box"></div><!-- /info -->
        <div class="phone box"></div><!-- /phone -->
    </div><!-- /hud1 -->

    <div class="speed">
        <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="hud2">
        <div class="status box withfocus">
             <h1>Estado</h1>
        </div><!-- /status -->

        <div class="media box withoutfocus">
             <h1>Multimédia</h1>
        </div><!-- /media -->

        <div class="environment box withoutfocus">
             <h1>Ambiente</h1>
        </div><!-- /environment -->

        <div class="settings box withoutfocus">
             <h1>Definições</h1>
        </div><!-- /settings --> 
    </div><!-- /hud2 -->
</div><!-- /wrap -->
```

Here’s the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/marisaroque/mR7nq/

EDIT:
Here’s the image:
[Link](http://oi62.tinypic.com/2hzs21v.jpg)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sorry could you please add the image which shows your desired result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/HUmLb/embedded/result/ ?

The key is making `.hud1` a one-column flex, and in the last item inserting a `.hud2` `row`.

I still couldn't make it center vertical, but I presume it's a good start.

Let us know.

#### Edit

http://jsfiddle.net/ngxyW/

I put an empty box in the lower corner and `fixed` the `wrap` div to bottom left.

This is a great reading about flex display: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I didn’t even think about that solution, it really help me a lot. Now what I need is to lean everything against the bottom left corner of the page. Another thing that I want to do is to have the circle with twice the height and width of the boxes (and that don’t change its size and form when one shortens the window), like in this image.
[link](http://oi62.tinypic.com/2hzs21v.jpg)

Comment: Thank you once again for your huge help @Niloct! In my project, I’ve adapted your suggestions and it’s almost like I wanted it to be (you can check here). http://jsfiddle.net/marisaroque/AAK46/ 
Now, to be perfect, I just need to make both the column and the line occupy the all page responsively. Do you think I’ll make it work using the flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis properties?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, apply `flex: 1 1` to `.hud2 > .box`, you will see every horizontal box will grow, INCLUDING the first empty. So you will have to remove `.box` class from the empty box, and dimension it with padding, margin, width and height, all with `!important`.